# How to prevent bootstrap tabs from destroying inactive content? [stateful tab switching]

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap tabs are great but they have an annoying downside: content on the inactive tabs gets removed from the flow of the page. in other words when you switch to a new tab, the previous tab's `display` attribute sets to `none` (instead of setting `visibility: hidden` or using other methods)

In my case I have dynamically positioned elements using [Masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/) on  the tab `foo`, whenever I switch to `bar` and then switch back to `foo` I have to re-calculate their position since they are all at `top: 0px; left: 0px;`

this is a costly behaviour, another example is when you have a form filled with data on the tab `foo` and then switch to `bar`, all the filled data would be lost so you have to re-enter everything back on.

what is the best workaround to keep the previous tab's state intact while switching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround works fine for me so far:

you can override these classes so the content on tab `foo` becomes "hidden" not totally removed from the page.

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-content>.active {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Note: you can also set `width: 0` if you have horizontal overflow, please don't forget to reset the `width` attribute back to normal under `.tab-content>.active{...}` .